# How to git log from all branches for the author at once?

Tags: git

I need to get the report of all commits that the author did.  So far, I have the script that wraps the following command:

```
git log --pretty=format:"%ad:%an:%d:%B" --date=short --reverse --all --since=2.months.ago --author=Petr
```

It works fine.  However, it reports only the actions of the current branch.  Is there any option that would log the commit messages for the author **from all branches**, not only from the current one?

In other words, can git make a reverse sorted (by datetime) sequence of all the commits in repository and extract the log info from that sequence?

**Solved:** (copied from the comment below that is hidden otherwise)

The problem was that I have one repository and two clones to work concurrently on two branches. I did push the changes to the origin repository, but I forgot to fetch the changes to the cloned repository. This way it seemed that `--all` did not work when using it for the cloned repository.

Comment: Guess you can write a shell script for that: `git log` accepts `committish` as its first argument: `git log mybranch` (and list all you branches with `git branch`).

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov: I probably do not understand.  What is the `committish`?  Is it possible to get the information via one git command?

Comment: Oh, `committish` denotes a branch or a commit (or HEAD). This does not seem to be possible with plain `git log` (since it uses `git rev-list` behind the curtains, which will _"List commits that are reachable by following the parent links from the given commit(s), but exclude commits that are reachable from the one(s) given with a ^ in front of them. The output is given in reverse chronological order by default."_ I'll try to come up with a viable shell script solution.

Comment: I'm getting commits from all branches, not only the current one? This is expected since you provide `--all`. Your command is correct

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov: Don't bother with `git rev-list` parsing, `git log --all` is OK.

Comment: @CharlesB: That was what I thought about the `--all`, but it apparently does not work this way for me.  I do not understand its help explanation: Pretend as if all the refs in `refs/` are listed on the command line as `<commit>`.

Comment: does a simple `git log --all` misses branches?

Comment: @CharlesB: Yes and no!  You could not know my situation, and I did not know what should I describe.  The problem is that I have one repository and two clones to work *concurently* on two branches.  I did push the changes to the *origin* repository, but I forgot to fetch the changes to the cloned repository.  Please formulate the comment to accept it.  If possible, how can I run the command against the origin repository?  The *origin* is the bare repository and the script is contained in the repository. (Otherwise, I will fetch from origin first [in the script].)

Answer (score 276, accepted):

Your command is right, since you use the `--all` switch which gives all commits from all branches. To answer the question in your comment, it works also in bare repositories.

```
git log --all --author=Petr
```

Answer (score 105):

Instead of `--all` you may want to use `--branches`, since `--all` also includes `refs/tags` and `refs/remotes`.

```
git log --branches --author=Petr
```