# Will git log show commits from all remote branches (if I have just fetched)?

Tags: git

Will `git log` show all commits from all remote branches (if I have just `fetch`ed)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git log` shows the commits that lead up to the current HEAD only.

Comment: I would like to perform the equivalent of `git log --author "foo"` on all commits the repository contains. How can I do this?

Comment: Looks like you can use the --all command switch.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10349302/how-to-git-log-from-all-branches-for-the-author-at-once