# How to list the most recent commits from every author, across all branches?

Tags: git, git-log

I would like to find inactive developers who did not commit in a long time.

How can I list the latest commit from each author, across all branches to see when each developer was last active?

Comment: Almost the same question was asked here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10349302/how-to-git-log-from-all-branches-for-the-author-at-once but only for particular author

Answer (score 3):

```
git clone --bare <url_to_repo> -- foo
cd foo
git log --branches --pretty="%ad %an" --date=iso --no-merges | sort -k4,4 -u
```

Clone a bare repo to retrieve the latest branches.

`--branches` instructs to go through all the branches.

`--pretty="%ad %an" --date=iso` formats the commit string with the author date in `iso` format and the author name. You may want to use `%cd %cn` for the committer date and the committer name.

`--no-merges` excludes the merge commits. If you want these commits, remove it.

`sort -k4,4 -u` sorts the output and remove the duplicated lines whose 4th columns are the same name. The left is the latest commit string, the date and the name.

Comment: This didn't seem to work: I got "Input file specified two times."

Comment: @mikerodent Try the commands in `git-bash` instead of windows `cmd`.