# Find latest commits to a file across all local branches with git - compare across local branches

Tags: git

So I'm working on a bunch of branches. And I remember, that on one of these branches, I did some super-smart change to a file. But I can't remember which branch this happened in.

Are there a git-command, that can show me all the latest changes to a file, across all the branches I have locally, for a repository?

**Example**

```
    /---D
   / 
  /   /---E
 /   / 
A - B - C
 \
  \
   \--F
```

I'm sitting on C and I know that I've made a super-clever commit in either D, E or F, to a specific file.

I could go through them one by one, to see the contents of the file. But I was hoping for a command like this:

```
$ git magic-command-1 "path/to/target/file"

Commit 123456 on branch "F" at 2022-05-19 15:10
Commit 234567 on branch "E" at 2022-05-19 14:33
Commit 345678 on branch "D" at 2022-05-19 11:12
```

and maybe also something that shows the differences.

---

I tried this:

```
git log -p -- cypress.development.json
```

But I'm not sure if it show across all branches or not. Or which branches the given changes show.

I also read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10351263/1766219) about something about an `--all`-flag, but the output doesn't show which branch the change is made on:

I also looked at the `--source`-flag, but the results doesn't really make any sense to me.

Regardless of what I do, I feel like I'm missing a command to appropriately compare the same file across all local branches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## TL;DR

Use `git branch --contains` with the hash IDs you find.  But: why do you care?  The hash ID is all you really need.

## Long

There's a basic problem here with your diagram: it has no branch names on it.  Let's put some branch names on it and then ask a key question:

```
    /---D   <-- br1
   / 
  /   /---E   <-- br2
 /   / 
A - B - C   <-- br3
 \
  \
   \--F   <-- br4
```

Which *branch* is commit `A` on?

**Warning:** this is a trick question!  The answer is below, with (I hope) enough text in between so that you can't just cheat and read it, and will instead have to think about this.  The *obvious* answer is "it's on `br3`" but this isn't right.  (It's not *wrong*, it's just not *right*.)

#### What you will want to do

> I also read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10351263/1766219) about something about an `--all`-flag ...

Use this flag, then use `git describe` or `git branch --contains` with the found commit hash IDs, or:

> I also looked at the `--source`-flag, but the results doesn't really make any sense to me.

The `--source` flag does what [the `git log` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) says it does:

> `--source`
>       Print out the ref name given on the command line by which each commit was reached.

but, as is common, the reference manual is terse and laden with jargon here.  The flag gets you *some* of the information you need, and *sometimes* it will be everything you need, but `git branch --contains` or `git describe` may still be *more* useful.

#### The answer to the trick question

Commit `A` is on *every* branch.

The trick here is that in Git, many commits are on many branches simultaneously.  Some commits may be on *no* branch.  This gets us into a separate Git question, which is: [What exactly do we mean by "branch"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25068543/1256452)  The word *branch* in Git is actually ambiguous, and overused, sometimes to the point where it nearly loses all meaning.  Once you get used to the crazy multiple meanings, though, it turns out that humans *usually* assign the *right* meaning automatically: a branch is a *branch name*, but it's also a *remote-tracking name*, a particular commit that Git calls more formally a *tip* commit, and a *set of commits ending at the tip commit*.  A Git branch is all of these things, and yet, when a human says "branch", they usually mean only *one* of these things.

To make any sense out of this, we need the concept of *reachability*.  Reachability is actually a graph-theory thing.  The diagram you drew is a *commit graph*, with the letters `A` through `F` standing in for actual commits.  Each actual commit has some unique, big and ugly and random-looking *hash ID*, but those are too hard for humans, so we mostly ignore them whenever we can, or use substitutes like these letters `A` through `F` here.

Each commit links *backwards* to a previous or *parent* commit.  Here, commit `C` links backwards to commit `B`, which links backwards to commit `A`.  Commit `D` links backwards to `A` as well, and so does `F`; `E` links backwards to `B`, which we already noted links backwards to `A`.

By following the backwards-pointing links, Git *finds* the commits.  Git finds the *end* commits—the *branch tip* commits—using the *branch names*, which are what humans tend to care about and use.  But then Git works backwards from there.

When we start with, say, `br1`, Git will find commit `D`, then work backwards and find commit `A`.  This means commit `A` is "on", or "contained in", branch `br1`.  But we can also start with `br2` and find `A`, and we can start with `br3` and find `A`, and so on.  Indeed, since `A` is our very first commit, [all roads lead to <s>Rome</s>](https://writingexplained.org/idiom-dictionary/all-roads-lead-to-rome) `A`: commit `A` is on *every* branch.  It will be on future branches too.<sup>1</sup>

It is literally impossible, in Git, to know which branch a commit was *created* on unless you record that as text in the commit message.  That's because we can create and destroy branch names at will: each branch *name* simply selects (or "points to") some commit *in* the commit graph.  We pick this commit at the time we create the branch name.

Then, when we *check out* (switch to) the branch and make a *new* commit, Git makes the new commit such that it points backwards to the commit we had checked out, and *stores the new commit's hash ID into the branch name* so that the new commit is now the tip commit.  So, given your diagram, if we `git switch br3` and make a new commit, the name `br3` will point to our new commit `G` afterward; `G` will point backwards to `C`; and commit `A` remains on every branch.

If we *delete* branch name `br1` entirely, commit `D` becomes *un-findable*, because we find the commits using branch names and working backwards.  There's only one way to find `D` right now, and that's to use `br1`.  So by deleting the *name* `br1`, we "lose" commit `D`.  It becomes *unreachable*.<sup>2</sup>

So *reachability* means "how we get there".  We get to commits from branch names.  For much more on this concept, see [Think Like (a) Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/).

---

<sup>1</sup>It *is* possible, in Git, to create more than one root commit, and hence set up new branches that *don't* lead back to commit `A`.  But that's not very typical and we won't cover it here.

<sup>2</sup>Git will eventually *discard* an unreachable commit.  You do, however, get a grace period to get the commit back, typically a minimum of 30 days.  The problem is that you must find the commit's unique hash ID, which you would do using the branch name, but now that the branch name is gone... well, that's the dilemma.

---

#### Reachability, `git branch --contains`, and `git log --source`

Now that you understand reachability, `git branch --contains` will make sense.  You give `git branch --contains` some hash ID, e.g., the hash ID of commit `B` or `E` or `A`.  What `git branch --contains` does is:

- starting from *every branch name*, work backwards;
- if this reaches the commit, print the branch name

so when used with the commit hash ID `B` this will print `br2` *and* `br3`, as those are the two branch names that can reach `B`.

The `--source` option to `git log` simply prints whichever name `git log` was using *at the time it found some commit*.  This is actually *more* complicated to explain, because `git log` itself is pretty complicated!

What `git log` does is *walk the graph*, printing some of the commits it encounters as it goes.  That is, we give `git log` some number of starting points, such as one or more branch names or commit hash IDs.  The `git log` command takes these names and resolves them to hash IDs, or takes the hash IDs (which are already hash IDs), and finds the named commits.  It puts each commit into a [priority queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue).

If we run `git log` with *no* arguments, `git log` uses the special name `HEAD`.  This name is normally *attached to* one branch name.  Using `git switch` or `git checkout`, we control which *branch name* `HEAD` is attached-to; that's the branch that gets *extended* when we make a new commit, so it's pretty important!  That branch name is the *current branch*, and that's what `git log` shows by default: that is, running `git log` with *no* arguments means `git log` resolves `HEAD` to the *current* commit's commit hash ID, and puts that (single) hash ID in the queue.

Now that the queue has some commit or commits in it, `git log` takes the *front* entry off the queue.  Since the queue is a *priority* queue, there's a sorting order, *if* there's more than one entry in it.  But it's extremely common for the queue to have just the one entry!  For instance, if we run `git log` with no arguments, the *current commit* is the one entry in it when we start.  If we run `git log br1`, Git puts `F`'s hash ID into it, and again there's just the one entry.

Anyway, having taken the *front* entry *out* of the queue, `git log` now decides, based on any arguments you gave like `--no-merges` or whatever, whether to *show* this commit.  If it's supposed to show the commit, it does that.  We call this *visiting the commit*, as though we're on holiday and going to certain attractions or cities or whatever.

Next, having shown or not shown the commit, `git log` finds the *parent or parents* of the commit.  In your sample graph, each commit has exactly *one* parent, except for commit `A` which has *no* parent.  (A merge commit, if there were any, would have two parents.)  By default, `git log` puts *all the parents* into the queue, unless those parents have already been visited.

With its one parent, if we've just visited `F`, `git log` would put `F`'s parent `A` into the queue.  The queue *was* empty—`F` was the only thing in it at the start of all of this—so now there's again just one entry in the queue.  The `git log` command now takes out and visits the one commit *in* the queue, i.e., commit `A`.  It shows commit `A`, if it's supposed to do that, and then puts `A`'s parents into the queue.  There are no parents, so this puts nothing in the queue, and the queue remains empty.

Once the queue is empty like this, `git log` quits.  So by starting at `F` via name `br4`, we visit commits `F` and `A` and stop, and that's what `git log` would show.

If, on the other hand, we run `git log --all`, the code will put `D`, `E`, `C`, and `F` all into the queue.  There are now *four entries* so the priority really matters.  This priority causes `git log` to *sort* its output.  The default sort is based on the stored *committer date* in each commit, with later commits being higher priority.  So if commit `F` is the *latest* commit, that's the one that surfaces first.

We'll visit `F`, printing it out and putting its parent `A` into the queue: the queue now contains `A`, D`, E`, and `C` (in date order).  Let's say that `E` has the next-highest-priority date: `git log` will pop `E` out of the queue, visit it, and insert `B` into the queue.  Then `git log` will take the highest priority commit out of the queue—let's continue the theme and say this is `D`—and visit that one.  This would put `A` into the queue, but it's already there; it doesn't go in twice.  We now visit `C`, which wants to put `B` in the queue, but it's already there; we then visit `B`, which wants to put `A` in the queue, but it's already there; and we visit `A`, which is the last thing in the queue and puts nothing *into* the queue, and so `git log` finally stops.

The `--source` flag simply annotates each *output*, for any given commit, with the *name that first led Git to this commit*.  So for `C`, that's `br3`.<sup>3</sup>  For `B`, that's either `br2` *or* `br3`, depending on whether `git log` visited `C` or `E` first.

The visiting order depends on the priority order.  You can control this, to some extent at least, with options like `--topo-order` or `--author-date-order`.  But in a big graph, especially one with a lot of branch-and-merge action in it, it's very difficult to know which of many names might first reach some commit.  Only in small and simple graphs like yours here will you get something predictable.

---

<sup>3</sup>With `git log --all` you will see `refs/heads/br3` rather than just `br3`.  That's simply the *full name* of the branch.  All branches have short names like `br3`, and full ones like `refs/heads/br3`.  I like to think of the full name as what their mom (or spouse) says when she's mad at them, kind of like [Stella Mudd in these ST:TOS clips](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ag1EbxYKh_4).

---

#### Branch names don't matter

At the top, I asked why you *care* which branch(es) some commit is "on".  Sometimes you will actually care, and then asking the question *which branches contain this commit* is fine.  But if all you want to do is *see* the file, or see it as changes, just tell Git to show you the file, or show you the changes:

```
git show a123456:path/to/file
```

or:

```
git show a123456 -- path/to/file
```

The former shows the contents of the named file as stored in the named commit.  The latter takes the named commit (using the abbreviated commit hash `a123456`), finds its *parent* (singular<sup>4</sup>), and runs `git diff` on the two commits.  Then, because of the `-- path/to/file` *pathspec* at the end, it shows only the diff for that one file.  So you'll see what changed in that one file, in that one commit, with respect to its parent.

You can even extract the entire file *from* that commit, overwriting the current working tree copy, with `git restore`:

```
git restore --source=a123456 --worktree -- path/to/file
```

Of course, you should first make sure you don't have anything valuable *in* `path/to/file`, because the copy that's in your working tree is *not in Git* and Git cannot get it back after you tell Git to *overwrite* it.  Only *committed* files are actually stored in Git.

This—the saved copy of the file, or the changes from the parent—is usually all you care about.  These are easy to get once you have the commit's *hash ID*.  That hash ID is the "true name" of the commit: it *always works* to identify *that one particular commit*.

The point of a branch name, in Git, is just to help you find commits.  The hash IDs are their *real* names.  They're just too ugly to deal with: we have to use mouse cut-and-paste or whatever, once we have found them.  But if you have run a command that printed the hash ID of the commit you care about, just grab that with your mouse and get to work!

---

<sup>4</sup>A *merge* commit, which has two or more parents, causes a problem here.  Each commit holds a *full snapshot of every file*.  So to see what *changed* in some commit, we have Git use its backwards-pointing link from commit to parent.  The parent also has a full snapshot, so the parent commit contains the same file, unless the file itself is all-new.  Git can then extract the file from each commit and compare the two files and tell you what changed.

But a *merge* commit has *two or more* parents.  That's what defines it as a merge commit in the first place.  Since it does have at least two parents, we no longer know *which parent commit to use* to get the "earlier" version of the file.  There are two or more earlier versions!  The `git log` command, when used as `git log -p` to show commits as patches, *cheats* by default: it just *does not bother to show anything at all*.  The `git show` command works harder by default, doing something Git calls a *combined diff*.  We won't go into any detail here though.